# javascript math result lesser than 0 gets 0.0000000000

Tags: javascript

Why does javascript returns so many zeros and not just 0.24
And how can i disable javascript to do this. Because when im using a calculator i never get the result 0.24000000000002

```
var sum = (0.0001 * 2400);
```

result 0.2400000000002

Comment: `(0.0001 * 2400).toFixed(2)`

Comment: but i dont want fixed 2 because sometimes if the result is reallt 0.258 i want it to be 0.258 and not 0.25800000000004 example

Comment: reference: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: What about math.round() ?

Comment: what about console.log(0.0001 * 2400 / 10); ?

Comment: @Yoshi I strongly believe that I know enough about floating-point arithmetics, but this article looks awfully difficult for me - so much math, theorems, formulas. I think it will be too confusing for a user who knows nothing about it.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev On a first glance it very much looks like such. But it actually issn't all that complicated. It's even understandable if one would just skip the crazy formulas. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that your `sum` is a float which are known to not be very precise. This is a limitation of float values.

To fix this you need to round the decimals by either `Math.round` or `.toFixed`.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that can trivially be closed as duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

javascript always do that but you can make it show only 2 digits after the dot.

```
var sum = (0.0001 * 2400);
alert(sum.toFixed(2));
```